# Como eu posso exibir dados utilizando o JOIN?

Tags: banco-de-dados, join, tabela-banco-de-dados, inner

Estou fazendo uma seção no meu site chamada "Minha Prancha Ideal", nela o usuário insere seus dados(peso, altura, etc), é feita uma comparação no banco (`join`) e é retornado para o usuário o tipo de prancha ideal de acordo com o perfil dele.

Eu tenho uma tabela com a referência de todos os tamanhos e tipos de prancha de acordo com a altura, peso e experiência do usuário.

[image: Tabela de Referência]

Eu estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

Dividi em duas tabelas:
 - Tabela `dados_usuario`, obviamente, armazena os dados do usuário(Experiência, altura e peso); 
 - Tabela `prancha` possue os valores de referência(tipo, tamanho, peso e litragem) sobre cada prancha de acordo com a experiência, peso, altura do usuário.

-> Eu comparo a tabela `dados_usuario` com a tabela `prancha` e retorno para o usuário o modelo ideal. Como fazer isso?

De início eu pensei colocar os mesmos campos, tanto na tabela `dados_usuario` quanto na tabela `prancha`, fazer um `inner join` e ter os dados que quero.

Porém, as duas tabelas teriam valores duplicados.

```
`dados_usuario`      `prancha` 
    altura2            peso2
    altura2            peso2
    altura2            peso2
    altura1            peso1
    altura1            peso1
    altura1            peso1
         comparo e exibo...
```

Creio que essa não seja uma boa prática e nem a melhor maneira de fazer isso. Sei que há outros métodos de fazer isso.

A questão é, **qual a melhor forma de comparar esses dados?** 

**Como identificar qual linha é compatível com os dados que o usuário irá inserir?**

Meu banco:

```
CREATE TABLE DADOS_USUARIO(
     usuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nome VARCHAR(150) not null,
     email VARCHAR(50) not null,
     estilo VARCHAR(14) not null,        
     exp VARCHAR(13) not null, 
     altura VARCHAR(12) not null,
     peso VARCHAR(9) not null,
     PRIMARY KEY(usuario)
);

CREATE TABLE PRANCHA(
    prancha_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    tipo_prancha VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    tamanho_prancha VARCHAR(9) not null,
    meio_prancha VARCHAR(12) not null,
    litragem_prancha VARCHAR(8) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (prancha_pri)
);
```

INSERÇÃO DOS DADOS NA TABELA 'DADOS_USUARIO':

```
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'joao', 'a@a.com', 'Surf', 'INICIANTE', '<1,60m', '>90kg');
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'john', 'b@b.com', 'StandUP Paddle', 'INTERMEDIARIO', '1,81 - 1,90m', '81 - 90kg');
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'carl', 'c@c.com', 'Surf', 'AVANÇADO', '>1,90m', '71 - 80kg');
```

INSERÇÃO DOS DADOS NA TABELA `PRANCHA`:

```
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (1, 'FUN', '8', '21 polegadas', '43L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (2, 'FUN', '8.8', '21 polegadas', '43L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (3, 'LONGBOARD', '9.2', '21 polegadas', '55L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (4,  'PRANCHA', '5.5 a 5.8', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (5,  'PRANCHA', '5.5 a 5.10', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (6,  'PRANCHA', '5.9 a 6.0', '21 polegadas', '32L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (7,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.4', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (8,  'PRANCHA', '5.10 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (9,  'PRANCHA', '5.10 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '32L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (10,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '32L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (11,  'PRANCHA', '6.4 a 6.8', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (12,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (13,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (14,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (15,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '36L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (16,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '38L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (17,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 7.0', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (18,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 7.0', '21 polegadas', '38L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (19,  'PRANCHA', '5.5 a 5.8', '18 polegadas', '23L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (20,  'PRANCHA', '5.8 a 5.10', '18 polegadas', '24L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (21,  'PRANCHA', '5.10', '18 polegadas', '27L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (22,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.2', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (23,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.2', '19 polegadas', '29 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (24,  'PRANCHA', '5.10 a 6.0', '19 polegadas', '24L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (25,  'PRANCHA', '5.10', '19 polegadas', '26L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (26,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '27L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (27,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '29L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (28,  'PRANCHA', '6.2', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (29,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '25L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (30,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (31,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (32,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.2', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (33,  'PRANCHA', '5.11', '19 polegadas', '26L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (34,  'PRANCHA', '5.11', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (35,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '20 polegadas', '29L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (36,  'PRANCHA', '6.1', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (37,  'PRANCHA', '6.1 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (38,  'PRANCHA', '6.1', '19 polegadas', '27L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (39,  'PRANCHA', '6.1', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (40,  'PRANCHA', '6.1 a 6.3', '20 polegadas', '29L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (41,  'PRANCHA', '6.1 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (42,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '31L');
```

NO meu form, estão todos os valores de altura e peso. Visualmente ele coloca a altura e peso exatos dele. Porém, no `value` dos campos eu coloquei os valores da minha tabela:

Altura:

```
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.71m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.72m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.73m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.74m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.75m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.76m</option>
```

Peso:

```
<option value="81 - 90kg">88Kg</option>
<option value="81 - 90kg">89Kg</option>
<option value="81 - 90kg">90Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">91Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">92Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">93Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">94Kg</option>
```

MEU JOIN:

```
SELECT USU.nome,
       USU.exp,
       USU.altura,
       USU.peso,
       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
       PRAN.meio_prancha, 
       PRAN.litragem_prancha       
          FROM DADOS_USUARIO AS USU 
                INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN
                   ON(USU.usuario = PRAN.prancha_pri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o seguinte: Você está fazendo `JOIN` com duas tabelas que não se correlacionam. Não existe uma chave ou valor dentro de ambas que as correlacione, você está fazendo um `JOIN` do `Id do usuário` com o `Id da Prancha` e isso não faz sentido algum e dessa forma você jamais vai conseguir o que quer. Então tenho duas sugestões para você:

Você faz um select comum e trata isso dentro do código da aplicação, nesse caso você não precisa mexer no seu banco de dados

Você adiciona os campos de altura, peso, estilo e experiência de usuário na tabela de pranchas e faz um `JOIN` com todas ou apenas algumas

Eu não entendo nada de prancha então fiz apenas exemplo aqui e os dados retornados para mim serão diferentes dos seus porque seus valores estarão corretos.

```
  CREATE TABLE `PRANCHA` (
  `prancha_pri` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_prancha` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_peso` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_altura` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_exp` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_estilo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tamanho_prancha` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `meio_prancha` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `litragem_prancha` varchar(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Os dados que inseri de forma muito aleatória pois não sei qual prancha serve para cada caso

```
INSERT INTO `PRANCHA` (`prancha_pri`, `tipo_prancha`, `usuario_peso`, `usuario_altura`, `usuario_exp`, `usuario_estilo`, `tamanho_prancha`, `meio_prancha`, `litragem_prancha`) VALUES
(1, 'FUN', '>90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'StandUP Paddle', '8', '21 polegadas', '43L'),
(2, 'FUN', '>90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'StandUP Paddle', '8.8', '21 polegadas', '43L'),
(3, 'LONGBOARD', '81 - 90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'StandUP Paddle', '9.2', '21 polegadas', '55L'),
(4, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'StandUP Paddle', '5.5 a 5.8', '20 polegadas', '30L'),
(5, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'StandUP Paddle', '5.5 a 5.1', '20 polegadas', '30L'),
(6, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'StandUP Paddle', '5.9 a 6.0', '21 polegadas', '32L'),
(7, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '<1,60m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '6.0 a 6.4', '21 polegadas', '34L'),
(8, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '5.10 a 6.', '20 polegadas', '30L'),
(9, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '5.10 a 6.', '20 polegadas', '32L'),
(10, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '32L'),
(11, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '6.4 a 6.8', '21 polegadas', '34L'),
(12, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '6.2 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '30L'),
(13, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '30L'),
(14, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INICIANTE', 'Surf', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '34L'),
(15, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '36L'),
(16, 'PRANCHA', '81 - 90kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '38L'),
(17, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.2 a 7.0', '21 polegadas', '34L'),
(18, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.2 a 7.0', '21 polegadas', '38L'),
(19, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '5.5 a 5.8', '18 polegadas', '23L'),
(20, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '5.8 a 5.1', '18 polegadas', '24L'),
(21, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '5.10', '18 polegadas', '27L'),
(22, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0 a 6.2', '19 polegadas', '28L'),
(23, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0 a 6.2', '19 polegadas', '29 a 31L'),
(24, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '5.10 a 6.', '19 polegadas', '24L'),
(25, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '5.10', '19 polegadas', '26L'),
(26, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '27L'),
(27, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '29L'),
(28, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.2', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L'),
(29, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '25L'),
(30, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '28L'),
(31, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '30L'),
(32, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '6.0 a 6.2', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L'),
(33, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '1,81 - 1,90m', 'INTERMEDIARIO', 'Surf', '5.11', '19 polegadas', '26L'),
(34, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', 'Surf', '5.11', '19 polegadas', '28L'),
(35, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', 'Surf', '6.0', '20 polegadas', '29L'),
(36, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', 'Surf', '6.1', '20 polegadas', '30L'),
(37, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', 'Surf', '6.1 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L'),
(38, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', 'Surf', '6.1', '19 polegadas', '27L'),
(39, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', 'Surf', '6.1', '19 polegadas', '28L'),
(40, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', '', '6.1 a 6.3', '20 polegadas', '29L'),
(41, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', '', '6.1 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '31L'),
(42, 'PRANCHA', '71 - 80kg', '>1,90m', 'AVANÇADO', '', '6.2 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '31L');
```

Ai fiz um `INNER JOIN` simples

```
SELECT USU.nome,
       USU.exp,
       USU.altura,
       USU.peso,
       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
       PRAN.meio_prancha, 
       PRAN.litragem_prancha       
          FROM DADOS_USUARIO AS USU 
                INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN
                   ON USU.peso = PRAN.usuario_peso
```

E o retorno foi

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já para um `SELECT` mais detalhado e demais valores

```
SELECT USU.nome,
       USU.exp,
       USU.altura,
       USU.peso,
       PRAN.tipo_prancha,
       PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
       PRAN.meio_prancha, 
       PRAN.litragem_prancha       
          FROM DADOS_USUARIO AS USU 
                INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN
                   ON USU.peso = PRAN.usuario_peso AND USU.altura = PRAN.usuario_altura AND USU.exp = PRAN.usuario_exp AND USU.estilo = PRAN.usuario_estilo
```

O meu resultado foi mais especifico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema estava ocorrendo exatamente no modo que estava fazendo o  Join. O item principal da minha consulta é a experiência (`iniciante`, `intermediario`, `avancado`). Pois, cada em cada `experiencia` existe um único tipo de prancha de acordo com o peso e a altura do usuário (Conforme está na tabela).

Comment: Cada prancha tem um tipo de usuário (exp, altura e peso) único. Modifiquei o Join tendo a `experiencia` como item principal, seguido de altura e peso. Adicionei o campo `experiencia_ref` na tablea `PRANCHA`, fiz a comparação e funcionou extamente do modo que eu quero. Eu modelo único de acordo com o perfil do usuário. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Recriei as tabelas e criei os campos AlturaMaxima e AlturaMinima para resolver a questão das faixas e alterei o tipo do campo altura para Integer para a comparação entre as alturas ficar mais fácil e estou inserindo a altura em centímetros.

```
create table prancha ( nivel varchar(10),
   alturamaxima integer,
   alturaminima integer )

create table usuario ( nome varchar(30),
  nivel varchar(10),
  altura integer )


insert into prancha values( 'iniciante', 160, 0 )
insert into prancha values( 'iniciante', 170, 160 )
insert into prancha values( 'iniciante', 180, 171 )
insert into prancha values( 'iniciante', 190, 181 )
insert into prancha values( 'iniciante', 200, 191 )


insert into usuario values( 'pedro', 'iniciante', 200 )
insert into usuario values( 'joao', 'iniciante', 180 )
insert into usuario values( 'adriana', 'iniciante', 175 )
```

O select com o INNER JOIN trazendo a prancha ideal para o Pedro, o João e Adriana ficou assim:

```
select * from prancha a inner join  usuario b 
on a.nivel = b.nivel and
   ( b.altura >=  a.alturaminima and
     b.altura <=  a.alturamaxima )
```

Parece-me que resolve sua questão.

Comment: A questão da faixa de altura e peso não é problema. Como eu coloquei no post, visualmente o usuário insere sua altura e peso exatos. Ex: Pedro, 1,85, 79Kg. Mas eu salvo o `value` do campo e dentro do `value` eu coloquei as faixas que estão na minha tabela de referência. Está bem no final do post.

Comment: Meu problema é cruzar os dados do usuário com a tabela de referência. Ex: João, Surf, Intermediario, >1,60 - 1,70m, <60kg.  <- Dados de João

Comment: Olhando na tabela de referência, a `prancha ideal` para Joao é o tipo `PRANCHA`, `6.4 a 6.8`, `21 polegadas` e `34 litros`.

Comment: Como eu posso fazer esta comparação, entende? Comparar os dados de João com a tabela `prancha`. E retornar a linha equivalente.

Comment: Como no select que te passei estou comparando a altura do usuario com a alturamaxima da prancha. Nessa lista você pode ir adicionando todos os comparativos que quiser entre os campos da tabela prancha e os da tabela usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente deves normalizar seu banco de dados: [aqui](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~pet/jornal/maio2011/materias/recapitulando.html)

Sendo assim, podemos transformar sua tabela em 7 exemplo:

```
nivel / altura / peso / tipo / tamanho / meio / litragem
```

Sendo assim, você teria uma tabela igual a essa, só que com os ID das linhas das outras tabelas informando qual informação seria o que.
Por exemplo:

```
Prancha:
id_nivel, id_altura, id_peso, id_tipo, id_tamanho, id_meio, id_litragem, id
```

O ideal seria que você criasse uma tabela usuario somente com:

```
Usuario:
   id, nome, email, id_prancha
```

E com as informações que vierem de um form por exemplo você poderia adicionar o usuario ja com o id da prancha ou somente consultar a prancha por exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM prancha
INNER JOIN tabela_nivel ON prancha.id_nivel = tabela_nivel.id AND tabela_nivel.nivel == 'Inciante'
INNER JOIN tabela_altura ON prancha.id_altura = tabela_altura.id AND tabela_altura.altura = '1.60'
INNER JOIN tabela_peso ON ...
```

E assim por diante.
E dessa forma também para achar o ID da prancha que vai ser inserido na tabela usuario.
Lembre-se de criar INDEXES para os id com seus campos nas respectivas tabelas para ter uma consulta mais performatica.

Comment: E como eu iria saber qual modelo de prancha se adequa ao perfil do usuário se a tabela `usuario` não irá capturar nenhuma informação dele? Na tabela `usuario` eu capturei a `experiencia`, `altura` e `peso`. E na tabela `prancha`, onde está toda a relação dos tipos de prancha de acordo com a `experiencia`, `altura` e `peso` do usuário. Com o `inner join` comparei as duas tabelas (vide o exemplo da @Diefani) e consegui ter o retorno que queria. Sua ajuda com a normalização do  banco foi muito útil, obrigado!

Comment: No caso você tem que capturar essas informações antes de inserir o usuario, então por exemplo viria do site o que o usuario gravou no perfil dele, então antes de salvar vc pegaria o registro da tabela prancha que atende os dados do usuario, dai gravaria na tabela do usuario somente o id essa linha.