# Utilização de um join para junção de duas tables

Tags: banco-de-dados, join

Gostaria de saber se é possível e indicavel usar um join para "juntar" valores  contidos em duas `tables` feitas em um banco de dados do `SQL Server`. Eu criei duas `tables` e uma delas tem informações gerais de um cliente e a outra tem informações de contato. O que acontece é que eu separei essas duas informações em duas `tables` pois vou colocar essas informações dividias nas abas de um `tabControl` (duas `pages`, no caso).

Estava pensando em fazer um `join` pelo `ID` da tabela com informações gerais, pois assim eu poderia conectar todos os dados de cada registro.

E além disso, gostaria de saber se é necessário criar alguma classe para fazer a inserção dessas tables no tabControl ou tem como fazer só um select ou algo do tipo.

```
CREATE TABLE tblClientes (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Telefone varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Tipo varchar(255) NOT NULL, );

SELECT * FROM tblContato
INNER JOIN tblClientes
ON tblContato.ID=tblClientes.ID;
```

Comment: Eu aconselho criar uma view, mas join resolve também

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) para entender como funciona os JOINs.

Comment: Pergunta duplicada, abaixo algumas questões abordado o mesmo problema.

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135168/como-eu-posso-exibir-dados-utilizando-o-join?rq=1

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185372/pegar-dados-utilizando-join-em-duas-tabela-1-para-muitos?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Depois de escrever a SQL da forma que gere a tabela com os resultados pretendidos, você pode retornar essa tabela em um DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = ConexaoBancoDados.ExecReader(sql);
```

Depois você deve criar um elemento gridView para exibir os dados:

```
gridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Mas eu só quero exibir na tabControl, tem alguma dica pois estou com dificuldade de entender como colocar o valor das tables em duas tabPage

Comment: Você tambem pode usar um gridControl.DataSource = ConexaoBancoDados.ExecReader(sql);